# displayTag pagenation issue -next ,last ,CSV and EXCEL XMLis not working

Tags: spring-mvc, displaytag

**NEXT ,LAST,CSV,XML**
i am not able to use the displaytag property like next,last,CSV ,XML etc
The code goes like this as show below

```
        <link href="resources/displaytag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="resources/alternative.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <body>

        <form:form action="date" method="get" >

            <display:table name="billingLogReportPojoList" id="billingLogTable"
                    export="true" class="its" pagesize="10" >
                    <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true"></display:setProperty>
                    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.decorator" value="org.displaytag.sample.decorators.ItextTotalWrapper" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="billingLogReport.pdf" />
                       <display:setProperty name="export.rtf.decorator" value="org.displaytag.sample.decorators.ItextTotalWrapper" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.rtf.filename" value="billingLogReport.rtf" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.decorator" value="org.displaytag.sample.decorators.HssfTotalWrapper" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="billingLogReport.xls" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" />
                    <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="true" />
                    <display:column title="ID" property="pnrId" />
                    <display:column title="Request  Date Time" property="requestDateTime" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}"/>
                    <display:column title="Status" property="status" />
                    <display:column title="Trace No" property="traceNo" />
                    <display:column title="Reference No" property="referenceNo" />
                    <display:column title="PNR No" property="pnrNo" />
                    <display:column title="PNR Status" property="pnrStatus" />
                    <display:column title="Amount" property="amount" />
                    <display:column title="Ticket No." property="ticketNo"/>
                    <display:column title="Ticket Value" property="ticketValue" />
                    <display:column title="Passenger Type" property="passengerType" />
                    <display:column title="Given Name" property="givenName" />
                    <display:column title="Surname" property="surname" />
                    <display:column title="Mobile No." property="mobileNo" />
                    <display:column title="Email" property="email"/>
                    <display:column title="Taxes" property="taxes" style="white-space: nowrap;"/>

                </display:table>
          </div>      
        </form:form>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When i am clicking on like CSV it is not generating the file and giving error like 404

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `requestURI` parameter in `<display:table />`!
if you don't set it properly when you click on the link, the page will be initialized without any arguments!

here is a sample of correct code:

```
<display:table name="appUserAttendanceList" id="assetUserAttendance" htmlId="thetable"
                class="tableBorder" defaultorder="ascending" sort="list"
                pagesize="10" excludedParams="method" export="true"
                requestURI="/assetUserManagement.do?method=setAttendanceFromClient">
```

Comment: Hi Mohsen89z  what we have to put in requesrURI i tried with my URL but still i am getting the same error can you please elaborate more in the property we need to and i have one more question where the file like pdf or etc will be created shall we have to specified some path

Comment: can any one please help me out when i am clicking like PDF or other option to generate in display tag i am getting error like    File not found

Firefox can't find the file at http://localhost:8080/ai/getdata?startDate=11/02/2014&6578706f7274=1&d-4524115-e=5&tillDate=11/03/2014.

    Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

Comment: take a pic of the page!

Comment: i thought of putting the picture earlier only but i dont have that much point . Any how now i am able to generate the file like PDF and etc but now i  have some other issue like each time i am clicking the next its hitting the DB each time which is not good and other problem is that like i got 67 data from the DB and i have mention the page size 10 . i am getting 7 list like 1,2,3,4 etc when i am clicking 2 and 3 i am getting error bean not define and the rest like 4 ,5 ,6 and 7 are working fine . thanks in advance for your support

Comment: regarding to pdf generating after you finished loading the page: I had the same problem with Display-tag! I fix it with js and after the page loads completely, then I download the export files!